# Animate shift in Column Size

Tags: jquery, materialize

Working with Materialize CSS, I'm looking to see if there is a technique where I can animate a shift in column size

**For example:**

```
<div id="col1" class="col s6">Some Content</div>
<div id="col2" class="col s6">More Content</div>
```

**Would transition to:**

```
<div id="col1" class="col s8">Some Content</div>
<div id="col2" class="col s4">More Content</div>
```

Any thoughts or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Materialize CSS does not have a built-in transition for shifting column sizes. You can animate the transition by specifying a css `transition` for the desired elements,

```
div.col{
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

and using your preferred jquery method to toggle the classes.

```
$('.col').hover(function() {
    $('#col1').toggleClass('s8 s6');
    $('#col2').toggleClass('s4 s6');
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqy7bn2e/18/)

Comment: I know this is really old, but would you have any idea how i could achieve this but with one of the column completely disappearing and the other one taking the full s12 span ? I can't manage to make it work...